Inconsistencies in Estimation Problems: When is "Enough" Really Enough?
Problem 1: Randy
Randy has \$400. He wants to buy a video game player that costs \$299 and two video games that each cost \$53. Does he have enough money? Estimation:
Video game player: $299 ≈ $300
Video games: $53 x 2 ≈ $50 x 2 = $100
Estimated total: $300 + $100 = $400

Solution Response: No

Problem 2: Fred
Fred needs 400 game markers for a game. He has 96 red markers, 123 blue markers, 106 yellow markers, and 72 green markers. Does he have enough game markers? Estimation:
Red markers: 96 ≈ 100
Blue markers: 123 ≈ 120
Yellow markers: 106 ≈ 110
Green markers: 72 ≈ 70
Estimated total: 100 + 120 + 110 + 70 = 400

Solution Response: Yes
In both problems, the estimation results in exactly the needed amount (400). However, in Randy's case, the solution states that he does not have enough, while for Fred, it states that he does have enough. Why is there this difference? How should we interpret estimates in such close cases?

You should keep track, at least approximately, of the approximations you are making.  If the uncertainty in your approximations is greater than the margin in your answer you may be wrong.  In both these cases the approximate solution is exactly the value that splits yes from no answers.  That tells you that the approximations were too coarse.  In the first your first approximation is $\pm 1$ and your second is $\pm 6$ so your answer could be off by $7$ either way.  As that is enough to change your answer you can't be sure which answer is correct.  The second case is quite similar.
You can then look at the approximations you make and try to improve the ones that impose the greatest uncertainty.  In the first case the games impose an uncertainty of $6$ while the player only imposes an uncertainty of $1$, so let us use the exact value for the games.  The total cost is then estimated to be $53\cdot 2 + 300=406 \pm 1$  As the error in our estimate is smaller than the margin to the decision point, we can confidently say he doesn't have enough money.
